# How to define my own custom LANGUAGE Extension in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

```
{-# LANGUAGE CustomHaskellExtension #-}
```

Is there a way to define my own custom Haskell language extension?

If YES, please can you point me to the documentation or tutorial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and no, language extensions are a feature of the *implementation* of the language (so, the compiler), this means if you are using the common implementations of Haskell, such as GHC, there is no built-in way to add custom language extensions.

However, there is nothing (besides time and knowledge) stopping you from building your *own* implementation of Haskell that supports whatever crazy language extension you like.

Depending on what you actually want, [*Template Haskell*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Template_Haskell) might be a solution you can use instead.

Comment: Also look at [source plugins](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/extending_ghc.html#source-plugins), in the latest [GHC 8.6](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/8.6.1-notes.html#plugins)

Comment: [Here Oleg Grenrus uses source plugins](http://oleg.fi/gists/posts/2018-07-06-idiom-brackets-via-source-pluging.html) to interpret singleton lists `[_]` surrounded by parens `([_])` as [idiom brackets](http://strictlypositive.org/Idiom.pdf)